# Solving nonlinear stiff ODE system in python or matlab

Tags: python, matlab

My problem is stationary combustion equations (BVP) with temperature and concentration-dependent equations with a form similar to that:

```
d(Lambda(C_i, T)dT/dx)/dx-C_eff(C_i, T)*dT/dx+Q(C_i,T)=0, 
d(D(C_i, T)dC_i/dx)/dx-u*dC_i/dx+G(C_i,T)=0
i=1
```

These equations are pretty stiff and very non-linear because the source term exponentially depends on `T`.
Is there a Python or MATLAB package or solver or something that could help me? Standard MATLAB solvers are not suitable for such tasks. I have not tried Python yet, but I think it should be the same.

Comment: How about the stiff ode solvers from Matlab: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-stiff-odes.html

Comment: ode15s is for the IVP and my is BVP